# RestTemplate Mock throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, junit, mocking, mockito

I have a rest template that makes a call in a method in a service class like so:

```
public CustomerResponse someMethod() {
CustomerResponse response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null,  CustomerRes.class).getBody();
return response;
}
```

When trying to mock the restTemplate in my test class, it keeps throwing a NullPointerException on the line where the mock restTemplate is called:

```
public void checkResponseIsNotNull() {
CustomerResponse customerResponseMock = mock(CustomerResponse.class);
when(restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, CustomerResponse.class).getBody()).thenReturn(customerResponseMock);
CustomerResponse cr = service.someMethod();
Assert.assertNotNull(cr);
}
```

Why is NullPointer being thrown? I have mocked a RestTemplate before, just without the getBody() method which leads be to believe its that which is causing the null pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add one more level of mocking:

```
CustomerResponse customerResponseMock = mock(CustomerResponse.class);
ResponseEntity reMock = mock(ResponseEntity.class);

when(reMock.getBody()).thenReturn(customerResponseMock);
when(restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, CustomerResponse.class)).thenReturn(reMock);

CustomerResponse cr = service.someMethod();
```

Originally you were setting-up the `ResponseEntity` only and the `RestTemplate` still remained with the defaults.. thus returning null when `exchange` has been called.

Comment: Thanks, that helped solve the issue. Can you only do one level of mocking at a time?